# tf.constant and tf.placeholder behave differently

Tags: python, tensorflow, sonnet

I want to wrap the tf.metrics around a Sonnet module for measuring performance of each batch, and the following is the work I have done:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sonnet as snt

class Metrics(snt.AbstractModule):
    def __init__(self, indicator, summaries = None, name = "metrics"):
        super(Metrics, self).__init__(name = name)
        self._indicator = indicator
        self._summaries = summaries

    def _build(self, labels, logits):
        if self._indicator == "accuracy":
            metric, metric_update = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, logits)
            with tf.control_dependencies([metric_update]):
                outputs = tf.identity(metric)
        elif self._indicator == "precision":
            metric, metric_update = tf.metrics.precision(labels, logits)
            with tf.control_dependencies([metric_update]):
                outputs = tf.identity(metric)
        elif self._indicator == "recall":
            metric, metric_update = tf.metrics.recall(labels, logits)
            with tf.control_dependencies([metric_update]):
                outputs = tf.identity(metric)
        elif self._indicator == "f1_score":
            metric_recall, metric_update_recall = tf.metrics.recall(labels, logits)
            metric_precision, metric_update_precision = tf.metrics.precision(labels, logits)
            with tf.control_dependencies([metric_update_recall, metric_update_precision]):
                outputs = 2.0 / (1.0 / metric_recall + 1.0 / metric_precision)
        else:
            raise ValueError("unsupported metrics")

        if type(self._summaries) == list:
            self._summaries.append(tf.summary.scalar(self._indicator, outputs))

        return outputs
```

However, when I want to test the module, the following code works:

```
def test3():
    import numpy as np

    labels = tf.constant([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], tf.int32)
    logits = tf.constant([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], tf.int32)

    metrics = Metrics("accuracy")
    accuracy = metrics(labels, logits)

    metrics2 = Metrics("f1_score")
    f1_score = metrics2(labels, logits)

    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("utils-const", tf.get_default_graph())
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()])

        accu, f1 = sess.run([accuracy, f1_score])
        print(accu)
        print(f1)

    writer.close()
```

However the following code does NOT work:

```
def test4():
    from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug
    import numpy as np

    tf_labels = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None])
    tf_logits = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None])

    labels = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], np.int32)
    logits = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], np.int32)

    metrics = Metrics("accuracy")
    accuracy = metrics(tf_labels, tf_logits)

    metrics2 = Metrics("f1_score")
    f1_score = metrics2(tf_labels, tf_logits)

    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("utils-feed", tf.get_default_graph())
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()])

        sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)

        accu, f1 = sess.run([accuracy, f1_score], feed_dict = {tf_labels: labels, tf_logits: logits})
        print(accu)
        print(f1)

    writer.close()
```

The output of test3() is correct, 0.88. The output of test4() is wrong, 0.0. However, they should be equivalent.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not the `tf.constant` version that fails? I find `tf.metrics` having a weird behavior in combination with `tf.constant`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(1.)
mean_a, mean_a_uop = tf.metrics.mean(a)
with tf.control_dependencies([mean_a_uop]):
  mean_a = tf.identity(mean_a)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
tf.local_variables_initializer().run()

for _ in range(10):
  print(sess.run(mean_a))
```

returns, when run on the GPU,

```
0.0
2.0
1.5
1.3333334
1.25
1.2
1.1666666
1.1428572
1.125
1.1111112
```

instead of `1`s. It looks as if the count is lagging by one. (I am assuming the first value would be `inf` but is zero due to some conditions on `count`). A placeholder version of this code is running as expected on the other hand.

On the CPU, the behavior is even weirder, as the output is non-deterministic. Example of output:

```
0.0
1.0
1.0
0.75
1.0
1.0
0.85714287
0.875
1.0
0.9
```

Looks like a bug you could log on [tensorflow's github repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues). (Note that using running metrics on constants is less than useful -- but it is still a bug).

**EDIT** Now I also stumbled on weird examples with a `tf.placeholder`, it seems that `tf.metrics` has a bug that is unfortunately not limited to its use with `tf.constant`s.

Comment: I suspect probably tf.control_dependencies behaves incorrectly? I fire a issue to tensorflow: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19368

Comment: @YuruiMing I see the same problem without `control_dependencies`