# tf.metrics.mean_iou returns weird values when fed with a tf.constant

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to understand why `tf.metrics.mean_iou` returns different values in every trials. If input is same over for loop, I guess the output also should be the same. I expected `miou = 0.061`, but the following code returns unexpected values some times even if the inputs in every loop are the same. Could someone help me please?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

"""
iou=TP/(TP + FP + FN)
"""

num_iteration = 10
num_classes = 3
l = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 0],
              [1, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 1],
              [0, 2, 2, 0]])

tf_label = tf.constant(l, dtype=tf.int32)

p0 = np.array([[0.0, 0.1, 0.7, 0.3],
               [0.6, 0.3, 0.4, 0.9],
               [0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1],
               [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]])
p1 = np.array([[0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3],
               [0.6, 0.3, 0.4, 0.9],
               [0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1],
               [0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4]])


p2 = 1 - p0 - p1
p = np.stack((p0, p1, p2), axis=2)

tf_logit = tf.constant(p, dtype=tf.float32)
tf_prediction = tf.argmax(tf_logit, axis=2)

miou = tf.metrics.mean_iou(labels=tf_label, predictions=tf_prediction, num_classes=num_classes)
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=None, summary_op=None)
with sv.managed_session() as sess:
    for i in range(num_iteration):
        label, prediction = sess.run([tf_label, tf_prediction])
        mean_iou, update_op = sess.run(miou)
        print(mean_iou)
```

the above code returns different values in trials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in tensorflow when using `tf.constant`s with running metrics; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50395387/1735003).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I have saved my time.