# What do the return values of tf.metrics mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been trying to add some hopefully useful intermediate calculations used to derive my loss function to the `eval_metric_ops` dictionary for my evaluation `EstimatorSpec`. I have wrapped these in a call to [`tf.metrics.mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean) as it seemed to fit my needs.

The return type of this function is a `tuple` of `(mean, update_op)`, where `mean` is ostensibly the current mean and `update_op` is an operation that computes the new mean and returns it.

However, when I try to evaluate it I see that the `value` and `update_op` fields seem to be different. The documentation doesn't provide an explanation for this as far as I can see.

For example, take the following snippet of code:

```
    test_tensor = tensorflow.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
    test_mean = tensorflow.metrics.mean(test_tensor)

    sess = tensorflow.Session()
    sess.run(tensorflow.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tensorflow.local_variables_initializer())

    print sess.run(test_mean)
    print sess.run(test_mean)
    print sess.run(test_mean)
    print sess.run(test_mean)

    print sess.run(test_mean[0])
    print sess.run(test_mean)[1]
```

This returns the following:

```
(0.0, 3.5)
(1.75, 3.5)
(2.3333333, 3.5)
(2.625, 3.5)
3.5
3.5
```

The second value of the tuple is obviously an overall average of the input value, but the left hand side values seem to be asymptoting towards `3.5`, while the taking the zero-index of test_mean and evaluating it results in `3.5` directly, as opposed to the value that I get by evaluating the whole operation and then taking the index.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems there is a bug currently in the running metrics in `tf.metrics`. A bug has been filed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19368) and the discussion that triggered here [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392027/tf-constant-and-tf-placeholder-behave-differently/50395387#50395387).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful to know. What is the behaviour that you would expect? (should all values be 3.5?)

Comment: Yes, that's how I interpret the docs. At the very least the left hand side should be a running mean (either before the update or after), but it currently returns values that are neither and that are simply incorrect.